every weakly continuous functionals in my separating family of functionals on a vector space.

I am reviewing some older propositions. There are two things that I am confused about. Given $x \in X$, then consider $(\epsilon/(\text{max}|\varphi_k(x)|) \cdot x$. The issue is that $$ \left|\varphi_k\left( \frac{\epsilon}{\text{max}|\varphi_k(x)|} x \right) \right| < \epsilon$$for every $k$ except the for the $j \leq n$ that satisfies $|\varphi_j(x)| = \text{max}|\varphi_k(x)|$. So I can't apply the continuity property.
Why does $\varphi = \sum \alpha_k \varphi_k$ imply that it's in my separating family of functionals that induce the semi-norm topology?

Missing hypothesis. The result is not true for an arbitrary separating family.

@geetha290krm This is in Pedersen Analysis Now textbook. Do you think that the author made an error? What do you think the hypothesis would be?

Does it say 'separating vector space of functionals'?

@geetha290krm oh I see lmao.
